# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Deploying Simple Node API

Tags: amazon-web-services, express

I am trying to deploy the simplest of all Node/Express APIs. It has one file, app.js, and the package. Here is the entire app.js file:

```
'use strict'; 

const express = require('express'); 
const app = express(); 

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({message: "hello"})
}); 

app.listen(8080, () => console.log('Application running'))
```

Again, it could not be simpler. When I try to upload a zip version of this file and package.json, I get an error:

```
Environment health has transitioned from Pending to Degraded. Initialization completed 79 seconds ago and took 4 minutes. Impaired services on all instances.
```

I am new to Elastic Beanstalk. I'm using the UI on amazon.aws.com to do the upload. This is kinda driving me crazy. Can someone help me figure out what's going on?

Comment: Did my answer help? If not, I think I know what other things may cause this, but first I want to know if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Elastik Beanstalk doesn't allow you to use any port you want. You need to use the Elastik Beanstalk's environmental variables (you can read more on environmental variables [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Environment_variables)). There is a sample code available on github [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/eb-node-express-sample/blob/master/app.js), using express on an Elastik Beanstalk instance but here's your code that should work with Elastik Beanstalk:

```
const express = require('express'); 
const app = express(); 

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({message: "hello"})
}); 

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(port, () => console.log('Application running'))
```